# Java count external methods calls

Tags: java, dependencies, method-call

I have a Java project using many external frameworks and libraries and I'd like to get the number of these external components methods calls. I've tried many tools for static Java code analysis but none give me the number of external (I mean of external libraries) method calls, just the number of different external classes used.

Is there a way to get this number?

Comment: I don't believe closevotes are in order on this question yet. idell: It still would be good to see what you've tried.

Comment: Sorry: i've tried Google CodePro Analytics and Class Dependency Analyzer, but reading features of many tools, no one tell about external method calls.

Answer (score 0):

You can try [JArchitect](http://www.jarchitect.com) to count external methods and classes calls, for that you can use CQLinq and execute queries like this

```
from m in ThirdParty.Methods select m
```

or if you want only external methods used by a specific project

```
from m in ThirdParty.Methods where m.IsUsedBy("projectname") select m
```